# how can i access a variable in enum

Tags: c, struct, enums, typedef

```
#define NUMBER_OF_CARDS 54

typedef enum type{
        QUEEN;
        JACK;
        KING
} CardTypes;

typedef struct game{
        CardTypes cards[NUMBER_OF_CARDS];
        struct{
               int hearts;
               int spades;
               int clubs;
               int diamonds;
        }
        int players_cards;
}GameState;
```

I have something similar like this and I want to access any variable from `enum` when this function is called

```
void set_cards(GameState gamestate, int x, int y, CardTypes cardtypes){
         gamestate.cards[x * y] = cardtypes;
}

void generate_game(GameState gamestate){
         /*
                some code 
         */
         if(variable == 0){
                set_cards(gamestate, x, y, gamestate.cards[NUMBER_OF_CARDS].JACK; 
                //This is what I have tried but it doesn't work
```

I hope you understand what I mean, because I really don't know how to explain this any better.

```
set_cards(gamestate, x, y, gamestate.cards[NUMBER_OF_CARDS].JACK;
//this is what I have tried but it doesn't work
```

please ignore any inaccuracies in the code. what is important for me is how can i access any of the enum's variable in the function generate_game().
this right here: `if(variable == 0){ set_cards(gamestate, x, y, gamestate.cards[NUMBER_OF_CARDS].JACK;  //This is what I have tried but it doesn't work`

Comment: Not sure what intend, but `gamestate.cards[NUMBER_OF_CARDS]` is out of bounds of the array. If you want specific positions of `cards` contain enum values then you need to assign: `cards[0] = QUEEN; cards[NO_OF_CARDS - 1 /* note: maximum valid index */] = KING;`

Comment: cards is an array of integers(enums). And integers don't have any members so the '.' operator will not work. And as Aconcagua said, you are indexing out of bounds.

Comment: r3k0j,  Rather than "but it doesn't work" post the error message or the unexpected output.

Comment: the thing is i don't get any errors. i just don't get the desired output @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @r3k0j "don't get the desired output" is insufficient.  What was the input, what was the output, what was the expected output?  Post a [mcve] so others may best help.

Comment: how can i access JACK for example in the generate_game function? @Fredrik

Comment: Enums values actually are just constants, and in this respect they do not differ from integer literals. `QUEEN == 0`, `JACK == 1`, `KING == 2`. `int n = QUEEN;` does not differ from `int n = 0;` How would you want to *access* them?

Comment: Oh, and you need to separate the enum names with comma, not semi-colon!

Comment: Maybe you have a fundamental misunderstanding: `enum`s are *not* like `struct`s – they are bunch of *constants*, nothing more, there are no member variables as in structs. Equivalently you could have simply done: `#define QUEEN 0 #define JACK 1 #define KING 2`, but the enums relieve you from having to define the values individually.

Comment: @r3k0j look at what Aconcagua said, there is nothing to 'access'

Comment: i want to access them in the generate_game function. i only get the gamestate struct as an argument and through gamestate i want to access any enum value. here for example:  set_cards(gamestate, x, y, **gamestate.cards[NUMBER_OF_CARDS].JACK**);   i just want to have JACK there @Aconcagua

Comment: @r3k0j What's the sense of `77.JACK`? Apart from the concrete value that's what you are trying to do. If you want to check if a position *contains* a value, then compare: `if(gamestate.cards[0] == JACK) { ... }` – note the double equal sign, in contrast to my first comment.

Comment: Wait a second – you just want to pass the value of `JACK` to the function, do you? Then it's just so much simpler: `set_cards(game_state, x, y, JACK);` –  enum constants reside in exactly the same scope as the entire enum does...

Comment: i want to make the 13th card a jack for example. i have to do that with the help of the set_cards() function. i have another function get_cards(){ return gamestate.cards[x * y];} but i only get the null operator for every card. so the set_cards function doesn't set the value at index i of the array to any of the enum values that i want @Aconcagua

Comment: yes i tried this: set_cards(game_state, x, y, JACK);, but still i only get the null operator and not any of the enum's values @Aconcagua

Comment: Are you aware that you provide the `GameState` object *by value*? This means that you create a *copy* of the object and inside the function, you modify this one then, leaving the original object untouched. You need to pass by *pointer* instead: `set_cards(GameState* state, ...) { state->cards[n] = value; }` and `set_cards(&gamestate, ..., JACK)` – note the ampersand.

Comment: or is it the fault of my set_cards function? that i only get the null-operator? @Aconcagua

Comment: i think your last comment solved my problem. i will try it and let you know if it worked @Aconcagua thanks a lot

Comment: @r3k0j Just as a hint: Next time better provide the code that compiles already (`set_cards(state, x, y, JACK);`), the other code (`gamestate.cards[NUMBER_OF_CARDS].JACK`) – paired with, let's say, suboptimal wording (*'access'*) – was a red herring leading everyone (including myself) into the wrong direction of what your problem actually was about...

Comment: thank you for your help so far(and i'll be sure to keep your hint in mind) but it still doesn't quite work. i still get the null operator for every card. i think my set_cards function is the problem here. @Aconcagua

Comment: @r3k0j What are your values for x and y? You possibly access the array out of bounds (thus write anywhere else -> undefined behaviour). At the moment I can just guess – you should provide an [mre] so that we can follow.

Comment: Important, too: `generate_game` has exactly the same problem, I assume you are calling that one from `main`. Of course must be `generate_game(GameState* gamestate)` as well...

Comment: https://ideone.com/JVRixJ

Comment: thank you for your help. i was able to solve my issue. indeed the problem was not using pointers in the other functions as well. @Aconcagua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon what @Aconcagua wrote your code should be using pointers :

```
// gamestate is a structure , so it must be passed as pointer to enable modification to be seen by caller
void set_cards(GameState *gamestate, int x, int y, CardTypes cardtypes){
     gamestate->cards[x * y] = cardtypes;
}

void generate_game(GameState *gamestate){ // here also pointer so caller know the changes 
     /*
            some code 
     */
     if(variable == 0){

        // next depends on what you intend to do :
        // 1- set the current games rate card with value of last card
        set_cards(gamestate, x, y, gamestate->cards[NUMBER_OF_CARDS-1]); 

        // 2- set the current gamestate to JACK
        set_cards(gamestate, x, y, JACK);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your types do not have too much sense. Card is defined by its colour and type.

```
typedef enum {
        QUEEN,
        JACK,
        KING,
        //you neeed some more
} CardTypes;

typedef enum {
    HEART,
    SPADE,
    CLUB,
    DIAMOND,
} CardColour;

typedef struct
{
    CardTypes type;
    CardColur colour;
}Card;

Card deck[54];
```

How to access:

```
void foo(Card *card)
{
    Card card1;

    card1.colour = HEART;
    card1.type = JACK;

    card -> colour = DIAMOND;
    card -> type = KING;

    card[34].colour = CLUB;
    card[34].type = QUEEN;
}
```

Comment: The terminology I've seen is ["suit" and "rank"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck), rather than "colour" and "type". (not a downvoter)